# json clicked points

Tags: javascript, json

I want to make a button which when clicked will show the xy coordinates of the points the user clicks with the mouse on an image. So far I have done this but it does not work:

```
<script>
var data_str = '{ "source": {' + 
           '"name":' +
           '[' + 
          '[' + pts_0[0][0]  +  ','  +  pts_0[0][1] + '],' +
          '[' + pts_0[1][0]  +  ','  +  pts_0[1][1] + '],' +
          '[' + pts_0[2][0]  +  ','  +  pts_0[2][1] + ']' +
           '],'
            '} }' ;               


</script>
<pre id='mydata'>
</pre>
<script>
document.getElementById('display-button').onclick = function (){
var data_el = document.getElementByID('mydata');
data_el.innerHTML = data_str;
}
</script>
```

When the button is clicked it should show something like this:

```
{
  "source": {
  "name": "myface.png",
  "points": [ ["10","23"], ["7","100"], ["77","11"] ]
 },
```

Comment: What is `pts_0`? I recommend against building JSON manually and use `JSON.stringify` instead to convert an array or object to JSON.

Comment: I don't understand. You need to print `data_str` JSON to `pre#mydata` element or...? What is the problem?

Comment: @seteh yes I need to print data_str to #mydata when button is clicked.

Comment: Can you describe what is or isn't happening when you try getting this to work? Does anything get displayed? How are you filling the `pts_0` array?

Comment: Nothing gets displayed at all. When an image is clicked I want the pts_0 to get filled. @bmceldowney